# Properties of a matrix built via a "matricization" of a unit vector

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices, singular-values

Suppose I have a unit vector $\vec v$, and I write it as a matrix, e.g., $16$-vector $\vec v=(v_1,\dots,v_{16})$, where $v_i$ is the $i$-th entry of the vector $\vec v$, is written as follows

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    v_{1}&      v_{2}&      v_{3}&      v_{4}\\
    v_{5}&      v_{6}&      v_{7}&      v_{8}\\
    v_{9}&      v_{10}&     v_{11}&     v_{12}\\
    v_{13}&     v_{14}&     v_{15}&     v_{16}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Are there some properties of this kind of matrices (some references might be okay), especially properties about the singular values of this matrix (e.g., the singular values are less than $1$ and the sum of the singular values are less than $2$, which are found numerically) when the dimension is not bigger than $4$?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/252819/339790).

Comment: the only constraint your matrix $M$ has is that ${\rm tr}\, MM^\top=1$; so the sum of the singular values squared equals 1; that's all.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker ... Didn't think about that... Thanks.